# How do I remove the bottom chord from a shed roof, the right way?

Tags: framing, roof, joists, structural, truss

I've got a 16' (length) x 10' (width) saltbox-style shed that I'd like to convert into an office. The roof is supported by simple triangle trusses of 2 x 4's. Each of the trusses is cantilevered out beyond the framing about 12". This is a simple 2d drawing of the framing, shown from the side of the shed, with the chord laying on the top plates:

[image: Shed side angle]

I'd like to know what my best options are for how to get more headroom in the space. I've thought about adding a 4 x 4 in the walls on each end of the shed and installing a ridge beam, but that wouldn't solve the cantilever problem. Collar ties would probably be sufficient for the size of this shed, if it weren't again for the cantilevers.

Could I use some sort of slider and wedge combo with plywood gussets to shore up the roof support? Or is there something else I could do?

Comment: Keep the same design but just increase the height of the walls.

Comment: Another option is to lower the floor.

Comment: How much more headroom are you looking for?

Comment: The chords sit at about 6' 3", and I'd like to get it up to 8 feet. Ideally, I'd open up the structure so I could vault the ceiling.

Lowering the floor is not a possible option, and increasing the height of the walls is complicated based on the shed placement.

Comment: Does your area have snow?

Comment: @Jack thanks for your answers - I'm in Edmonds, WA. Didn't use to have a lot of snow, but have had a couple of 10 - 15 inch storms in the last 5 years.

Comment: What's your insulation plan?

Comment: There are a lot of good ideas in the answers here, but I'd run any/all of them past a licensed Structural Engineer before settling on one of them. After all, you don't want the shed to come crashing down, destroying your office. Even worse if you happen to be in it at the time. The cost of the SE's time is (most likely) going to be less than the cost to rebuild and replace contents. Guaranteed to be cheaper if someone is injured in the collapse.

Comment: You don't  need to involve a structural engineer for a little yard shed. C'mon, man. :) Even if the roof failed it's extremely unlikely to "come crashing down". That's not how it goes. I've demolished enough stuff to know that without large spans and huge weight things just get crunchy and saggy. They rarely actually fall. This is an acceptable risk, IMO.

Comment: @isherwood I'll either be doing spray insulation or fiberglass

Comment: So how much height do you need for that, including roof ventilation? It's pretty important information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

As a variant on increasing the height of the walls, you could create a mini truss for the front and rear cantilever portions.  The vertical truss pieces should typically be 2/3 in for 1/3 cantilever.  See the annotated photo.  Add the ridge beam (roughly sized as two structural 2x12's nailed together from New Zealand residential codes) and add the green vertical truss piece and then remove the bottom chord.  The bottom cord keeps the walls from moving out under a roof load, so with the new design, the orange metal will be needed so the rafters can now take that force.  I would normally use 1/8" or 1/4" steel on both sides bolted on, but nail-on plates may be strong enough.

Lookup standard span tables for your country to figure out the ridge beam sizing and if you have any concerns, check with an engineer.

[image: Annotated changes]

### Option 2

Use a plywood box-beam inspired by the solution from @Jack.  This avoids having to add a ridge beam and would be what I would do personally.  See https://img.bretts.com.au/long_span_beams_span_tables.pdf for more details on box beams and span tables (in metric) to get familiar with this.  Add structural adhesive as well as the nails for extra strength.  The nails are critical, do not use screws unless they are specifically for structural applications and follow the nailing pattern.

You can try to do some truss calculations on your own using https://skyciv.com/free-truss-calculator/

[image: Plywood Box Beam]

Comment: Can you clarify the "orange metal" comment? It's not clear how the modified framing prevents the walls from tilting outward at the top.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate It (the orange hardware) means to make a moment connection to restrict the outward movement. I don't think 2x4s can handle the task.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea. How would I put these mini trusses together? Would I need to sister the studs and break through the top plate? And re: the structural ply, are you thinking gussets for that space? If you’ve got any articles or resources I’d love to see them.

Comment: @r13 is correct, the orange metal bracing (I should have said plates) take the moment that would cause the walls to spread outwards or fall inwards.  You would need some bolt-on plates for this as timber probably wouldn't be strong enough.  I based this upon designs from AS/NZS3604 which is the standard timber design handbook for New Zealand and Australia.

Comment: @JoshWinskill - for the studs above the wall, you either need to break through the top plate to install them or you can install them above the wall and add steel strapping down the front and back to ensure that it is as strong as a stud that has the 2/3 backspan.

Comment: @JoshWinskill - how much head room do you need?  There are some standard span tables that I might be able to find for plywood box beams that would be closer to what jack did below and you could probably get rid of the ridge beam as well.

Comment: @Eric - thanks for your follow up. I'd basically like to get as much as I can without re-designing the roof or modifying the existing walls. I'd like to be able to work out in here as well, so a full range of motion, at least near the roof apex, would be ideal.

If the weight isn't a problem, I'd like to put in a ceiling fan as well.

Comment: A ceiling fan will not stress the structure at all.  Wind (and potentially snow) loads will be your main concerns.  How long is the building?  That is a major factor in the sizing of the ridge beam.  You may want to add that to the original question as an edit.

Comment: @Eric updated to include; length is 16', and I need to figure out how to calculate the size of beam I'd need. Wind is not going to be a major factor, as the shed is low between trees and other buildings that tend to block it. Snow (1 ft or less) is a concern. Are these two options different solutions, or is the second answer an extension of the first? Would I need a ridge beam in the second scenario?

Comment: @JoshWinskill - 16' is long span for standard timber.  By New Zealand residential standards with a roughly 12" snow load, you would need two 290x45 (2"x12") structural timbers (SG8) nailed together.  SG8 is the standard pine structural grade for framing timber here.  Jack's profile shows he is a builder in the USA, so he might also have some advice here.  I'll update my answer with these details.  I think the extra 2x4 and ply will be your best solution since it avoids the ridge beam.

Comment: @Eric thanks again for your help. I think this is the most likely path for me to go. Should I still sister in those vertical truss pieces for added support?

Comment: The vertical pieces are not necessary with the second option.  Let me label those to make them more clear.  With this design, the plywood section is similar as a gusset at the apex of a traditional plywood joist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different take on another answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That may work, but I think the forces on the front box beam at the ridge are likely to exceed the capabilities of plywood.  Bolting on some steel brackets would fix that and make this viable.

Comment: @Eric ,both sides of the roof are essentially "hung" off of the ridge beam. The rafter tails of either roof only need to bear on the outside walls. There should only little if any splaying of the roof rafters in this configuration. The plywood and the associated 2X4s are to transfer the cantilevered roof load directly to the wall plate. The plywood is essentially a replacement for metal truss plates, nailed well enough so the shear forces are kept in check

Comment: as long as the gable ends have enough bracing and the building isn't too long, that should hold, then.

Comment: @Eric , Yes, that is the remark about the posts in the end walls. It looks like your answer is doing pretty good!

Comment: appreciate your inputs as well.  You may want to commented on North American sizing of timber and structural grades since you are the expert there.

Comment: @Eric I only go by what the code book recommends. In cases like this, I have called the in house engineer to get the spec needed for their materials, referring to the beam. I only have practical experience, Lee Sam is an engineer and has provided some great input on these types of issues as well.

Comment: @Jack I see by your profile that you're close to my neck of the woods. Do you have a local engineer you like to work with? I'm thinking I'll probably use the ply boxes to avoid having to put in a ridge beam if I can, and want to make sure I've got my angles and sizing right.

Comment: The plywood boxes I have shown are only part of the mod. The ridge beam is a very necessary part of the whole assembly. The drawings I modified isn't an either/or, it is a step by step drawing. First the 2X4s cut in place, covered by the plywood so the cut bottom will not buckle on the plate. If a ridge beam is not used, both the front and back wall will be pushed out so far, catastrophic failure will most certainly happen.

Comment: To answer the engineer question, I have only needed to use the in house engineers from the suppliers of the beams, LVLs in particular for sizing for the span and live loads I have. Everything else, the sizes for joists and rafter, etc are in the code book. FWIW, it is available online. It is a free service by the county. I don't think code will cover what you are looking for. I would go to the local lumber store you will get your materials from, take note where the materials come from, call that place and ask for their in house engineer. With some coaxing, they will help.